# How to import large number of posts in one domain to another domain?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site with almost 80,000 posts with featured images and categories. I want to migrate all those posts to my other site while retaining the featured images and categories.

I have exported the xml file from Wordpress' export option.

My XML file size is approx 260 MB.

When I import this XML file into my other site, it does not import all the posts.

The import option stops responding and no errors are shown.

How can I import all the posts with categories and featured images?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are importing data through WordPress importer plugin.
There is an errors in that plugin due to it is not updating since last 1 year.
So you have to find without error plugin from GitHub.

Noe come to the importing point.
Open your XML file in editor.

You will find '' section.
In this section you will find title, link, description and so on tags.

Now due to WordPress or any PHP server have import size limit, and exicution time limit are there in the configuration.

So you have to dived your XML file into small part of code.

Here is a step doing so. (Before follow the steps please keep backup your original XML file.)

1. Make one temp.xml file.
2. Copy the content from  tag and pest into your temp file.
3. After  tag you will find  tag. this tag contain your actual data of post.
4. Cut that some of item tag and pest into the temp.xml file. (You can take over 100 item together)
5. Close the channel and rss tag ' ' in the temp.xml file.
6. Do the same with your entire XML file.
7. And upload one by one.

Note: Do step 2 in each temp file.
It is time consuming but it will work.